I have selected the start and end date in Azure userstories/ tasks the error " The value for field 'Start Date' is not of the right type"
It's related to Azure Devops date format issue in userstories and tasks.
I have selected a date in Azure user stories, the date selected was in correct format but I am receiving the error as " The value for field 'Start Date' is not of the right type.". How can i resolve the issue? I couldn't do any manual entries as well. Please help me on this

Are you using custom fields in the affected work items or the existing Start Date field ? Have you created work items rules which may impact that? Test the existing Start Date field in User Stories, by default the format should like this 4/25/2024 12:00 AM, just try to enter it manually to see if it works. If the issue persists, please share detailed steps and screenshots to help clarify the issue so that we can research and test it further.

If it's a custom field, then please try to remove it from your work item process, and then add the existing 'Start Date' field to your User Story and Task work item type to see if it works. See Add a custom field to a work item type (Inheritance process) for details.

Hi, Actually I am unable to do any Manual entries for the user story/task.
default start date and end date format given as dd-mm-yyyy. When i select from the calendar receiving the error as "
The value for field 'Start Date' is not of the right type"

So, how did you define the "Start Date" field? Can you please share the detailed steps and screenshots? Can you please try to delete the field and then add it again by following the steps mentioned here :  Add a custom field to a work item type (Inheritance process) ?

If you are unable to do any Manual entries for the user story/task, then that means you do not have the permission to edit the work item or Start Date field is set to read only. Please check the rule settings to remove the read only rule, and then try it again.


I have opened my organization Azure devops
Opened one of the user story
Selected the start date.
Received the error


Can you please try to delete the field and then add it again by following the steps mentioned here : Add a custom field to a work item type (Inheritance process)?  Also check if there's a readonly rule for the field.  See Add a rule to a work item type (Inheritance process) for details.
